# In Go, what's the inverse of reflect.SliceOf()?

Tags: reflection, go

In Go, [`reflect.SliceOf()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceOf) makes a Type representing a slice of the given Type:

> SliceOf returns the slice type with element type t. For example, if t represents int, SliceOf(t) represents []int.

However, I already have a Type for `[]int` but want to get a Type for `int`. Is there an easy way to do that? (Note, I'm using `int` as an example. In reality, all I know is I have a slice, and I need to find what Type each element of the slice is.)

I'm trying to populate a slice of bool, int, float, or string, from a `[]string` using reflection... here's the relevant piece:

```
numElems := len(req.Form["keyName"])
if structField.Kind() == reflect.Slice && numElems > 0 {
    slice := reflect.MakeSlice(structField.Type(), numElems, numElems)
    for i := 0; i < numElems; i++ {
        // I have some other code here to fill out the slice
    }
}
```

But in order to fill out the slice, I need to know the type of the slice I'm filling out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, you already have the element type: `structField.Type()`. You can use `reflect.New(t).Elem()` to get an "editable" `reflect.Value` of a type.  Once you've populated that value, you can call `slice.Index(i).Set(...)` to assign that value into the resulting slice.

To answer the letter of your question though, if you do have a slice and need to populate it, say you have a `reflect.Type` of a `[]int`, then you can call `.Elem()` to get the `reflect.Type` for `int`.

See the [Type](http://godoc.org/reflect#Type) documentation for the methods you can call on a Type.

Comment: Bingo! `.Elem()` did the trick. That magic method does all sorts of things. Thanks for the thorough explanation. This is going toward the [martini-contrib/binding](https://github.com/codegangsta/martini-contrib/tree/master/binding) so I hope your answer will benefit many people.